# elasticsearch - tips on how to organize my data

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying elasticsearch by getting some data from facebook and twitter to.

The question is: how can I organize this data in index?

```
/objects/posts
/objects/twits
```

or

```
/posts/post
/twits/twit
```

I'm trying queries such as, get posts by `author_id = X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about the long term when deciding how to structure your data in Elasticsearch. How much data are you planning on capturing? Are search requests going to look into both Facebook and Twitter data? Amount of requests, types of queries and so on.

Personally I would start of with the first approach, `localhost:9200/social/twitter,facebook/` as this will reduce the need for another index when it isn't necessarily required. You can search across both of the types easily which has less overhead than searching across two indexes. There is quite an interesting article [here](https://www.found.no/foundation/sizing-elasticsearch/) about how to grow with intelligence.

Elasticsearch has many configurations, essentially its finding a balance which fits your data.

Answer (score 1):

First one is the good approach. Because creating two indices will create two lucence instances which will effect the response time.